# JS apply function to all values of object

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
const player = {
  id: 123,
  country: 'GB',
  names: { 
    key1: 'John Paul', 
    key2: 'Johny Paul',
    key3: 'Johny-paul'
  } 
}
```

Then I want to apply a function to all `names` values:

```
const normalizeString = el => el.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");

const normalizedPlayer = {
    ...player,
    namesNormalized: Object.keys(player.names).map(k => ({[k]: normalizeString(player.names[k])}))
}
```

But I get an array of objects instead of object:

```
{
  id: 123,
  country: 'GB',
  names: { key1: 'Jóhn Paul', key2: 'Johny Päul', key3: 'Johny-paul' },
  namesNormalized: [
    { key1: 'John Paul' },
    { key2: 'Johny Paul' },
    { key3: 'Johny paul' }
  ]
}
```

I want `namesNormalized` like this:

```
 {
    id: 123,
    country: 'GB',
    names: { key1: 'Jóhn Paul', key2: 'Johny Päul', key3: 'Johny-paul' },
    namesNormalized: { 
     key1: 'John Paul', 
     key2: 'Johny Paul', 
     key3: 'Johny paul' 
   }
 }
```

Comment: `map` returns an array. Use `reduce` and return an object.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) combined with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

This lets you avoid having to deal with reducing the properties as `fromEntries` turns the entries format back to an object.

From Entries works on pretty much all modern major browsers ([Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=fromEntries)), but there is a [shim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object.fromentries) for it if needed on older browsers.

```js
const player = {
  id: 123,
  country: 'GB',
  names: {
    key1: 'Jóhn Paul',
    key2: 'Johny Päul',
    key3: 'Johny-paul'
  },
}
const normalizeString = el => el.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
const normalizeObject = (obj) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [k, normalizeString(v)]))
const normalizedPlayer = {
  ...player,
  namesNormalized: normalizeObject(player.names)
}


console.log(normalizedPlayer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` method on `Object.entries` to return an object and assign it to `namesNormalized` property.

```js
const player = {
  id: 123,
  country: 'GB',
  names: {
    key1: 'John Paul',
    key2: 'Johny Paul',
    key3: 'Johny-paul'
  }
}

const normalizeString = el => el.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
const normalizedPlayer = { ...player }
normalizedPlayer.namesNormalized = Object.entries(player.names)
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => Object.assign(r, {
    [k]: normalizeString(v)
  }), {})

console.log(normalizedPlayer)
```

Comment: exact, I added in my answer the reduced version

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Heretic Monkey to use reduce:

```
const player = {
  id: 123,
  country: 'GB',
  names: { 
    key1: 'John Paul', 
    key2: 'Johny Paul',
    key3: 'Johny-paul'
  } 
}

const normalizeString = el => el.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");

const normalizedPlayer = {      
    ...player,
    namesNormalized: Object.keys(player.names).reduce( (a, k) => ({...a, [k]: normalizeString(player.names[k])}) , {})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through each key of the object and then assign that key to the normalized version, like this:

```
const generateNormalizedObj = (obj) => {
    const normalizedObj = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        normalizedObj[key] = obj[key];
    })

    return normalizedObj;
}
```

Then you could simply set the `namesNormalized` property in the last variable to be output of that function.

Here's the final code:

```
const player = {
  id: 123,
  country: 'GB',
  names: { 
    key1: 'John Paul', 
    key2: 'Johny Paul',
    key3: 'Johny-paul'
  } 
}

const normalizeString = el => el.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");

const normalizedPlayer = {
    ...player,
    namesNormalized: Object.keys(player.names).map(k => ({[k]: normalizeString(player.names[k])}))
}

const generateNormalizedObj = (obj) => {
    const normalizedObj = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        normalizedObj[key] = obj[key];
    })

    return normalizedObj;
}

const normalizedPlayer = {
    ...player,
    namesNormalized: generateNormalizedObj(player.names)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const player = {
  id: 123,
  country: 'GB',
  names: { 
    key1: 'John Paul', 
    key2: 'Johny Paul',
    key3: 'Johny-paul'
  } 
}
const normalizeString = el => el.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");

const normalizedPlayer = {
    ...player,
    namesNormalized: Object.keys(player.names).reduce((namesNormalized, k) => {
      return { 
        ...namesNormalized, // spread over previous key/value pairs
        [k]: normalizeString(player.names[k]) // store current key/value pair
      }
    }, {}) // initial value for reducer is an empty object
}
```